# Searching an Array of objects to return objects match a property value

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml, nspredicate

I have an array of objects (240 objects) to be precise, all objects have a property called "round", i want to have a second array where i can store objects if round == x.

x is whatever number i decide.

```
-(void) parseXMLFixtures
{

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"somethinggoeshereiwthanapikey"]];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *xml = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlString];

    NSMutableArray *items = [xml objectForKey:@"Match"];

    NSMutableArray *newFixtureObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in items) {
        FixturesObject *myFixtures = [FixturesObject fixtureFromXMLDictionary:dict];
        [newFixtureObjectArray addObject:myFixtures];
    }

    NSNull *nullValue = [NSNull null];

    [newFixtureObjectArray insertObject:nullValue atIndex:0];
    [newFixtureObjectArray insertObject:nullValue atIndex:1];

    [self setTableDataFixtures:newFixtureObjectArray];
}
```

Anyone knows how i could accomplish this?

//////

```
NSNumber *myRound = [NSNumber numberWithInt:11];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"round = %@", myRound];
NSArray *filteredArray = [_roundParser filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@" roundParser %@", filteredArray);



2014-02-13 01:00:18.383 [6864:70b]  roundParser (
)
2014-02-13 01:00:18.394 [6864:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101940795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001016a3991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f902f -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 175
    3  Sagres Companion           0x0000000100019ddf -[FixturesController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 175
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
int num = 11;
NSString *yourX = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"round = %@", yourX];
NSArray *filteredArray = [objectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

yourX is `NSString` of number that you need to find.

Comment: the array comes back empty

Comment: are you sure there is a matching object in `objectArray` with `round == X`?

Comment: yes i used 10, the array has 8 objects for each number from 1 to 30

Comment: what is the type of property `round`?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *round;

Comment: just changed the NSNumber for NSString withFormat and seems to be doing it

Answer (score 0):

Use Predicate it will apply search for you array:

```
NSPredicate *sPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.round like '%@'",yourX];
[array filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
```